# How to selectively carry over values in a SQL-server query from a previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set aggregated from multiple tables that looks like this:

```
f.dtmDate  | c.sglPart1 | d.sglPart2 | e.sglPart3
----------------------------------------------------
2016-08-06 | 56         | 36         | 65
2017-11-04 | 75         | 64         | 54
2018-02-03 | 0          | 52         | 78
2018-05-05 | 0          | 0          | 0
```

What I need to do is make it so that every result from the past year that is over a 70 carries down with each row so that it looks like this (based on current date of 2018-03-06):

```
f.dtmDate  | c.sglPart1 | d.sglPart2 | e.sglPart3
----------------------------------------------------
2016-08-06 | 56         | 36         | 65
2017-11-04 | 75         | 64         | 54
2018-02-03 | 75         | 52         | 78
2018-05-05 | 75         | 0          | 78
```

The following query is as close as I've been able to come with which returns this:

```
f.dtmDate  | c.sglPart1 | d.sglPart2 | e.sglPart3
----------------------------------------------------
2016-08-06 | 56         | 36         | 65
2017-11-04 | 75         | 64         | 78
2018-02-03 | 75         | 64         | 78
2018-05-05 | 75         | 64         | 78
```

... but I can't figure out how to make values under 70 not to carry over because I need the returned value of the nested Select functions to determine if I need to carry over the value.

```
select 
CASE WHEN f.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
THEN (
  SELECT TOP 1 tblMPpart1.sglPart1 
  FROM tblMPpart1 
  left join tblMPResults on tblMPpart1.intMPresultid = tblMPResults.intMPresultid 
  left join tblexams on tblMPResults.intExamID = tblexams.intExamID 
  WHERE tblMPResults.intrecordid = 1000 AND tblexams.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
  ORDER BY tblMPpart1.sglPart1 DESC) 
ELSE c.sglPart1 
END AS sglPart1, 
CASE WHEN f.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
THEN (
  SELECT TOP 1 tblMPpart2.sglPart2 
  FROM tblMPpart2 
  left join tblMPResults on tblMPpart2.intMPresultid = tblMPResults.intMPresultid 
  left join tblexams on tblMPResults.intExamID = tblexams.intExamID 
  WHERE tblMPResults.intrecordid = 1000 AND tblexams.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) 
  ORDER BY tblMPpart2.sglPart2 DESC) 
ELSE d.sglPart2 
END AS sglPart2, 
CASE WHEN f.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())  
THEN ( 
  SELECT TOP 1 tblMPpart3.sglPart3  
  FROM tblMPpart3  
  left join tblMPResults on tblMPpart3.intMPresultid = tblMPResults.intMPresultid  
  left join tblexams on tblMPResults.intExamID = tblexams.intExamID  
  WHERE tblMPResults.intrecordid = 1000 AND tblexams.dtmDate > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())  
  ORDER BY tblMPpart3.sglPart3 DESC)  
ELSE e.sglPart3  
END AS sglPart3,  
f.dtmDate as ExamDate,  
from tblMPresults b  
left join tblMPpart1 c on b.intMPresultid = c.intMPresultid  
left join tblMPpart2 d on b.intMPresultid = d.intMPresultid  
left join tblMPpart3 e on b.intMPresultid = e.intMPresultid  
left join tblexams f on b.intExamID = f.intExamID  
where b.intrecordid = 1000 
order by b.intrecordid, b.intexamid
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is for msSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblMPpart2.sglPart2
```

with

```
SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN tblMPpart2.sglPart2 >= 70 THEN tblMPpart2.sglPart2 ELSE d.sglPart2 END
```

If d turns out to be not accessible inside there, just replace it with NULL and then convert NULLs to d.sglPart2 outside.

Comment: This produces exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you may be able to solve this using the `LAG` aggregate function.

see
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/lag.php
or
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lag.php

Comment: I really like this answer in that it specifically answers the question of "carrying over" variables, and will likely be helpful in future applications, but I could only figure out how to make it carry one place, not in a way that would cascade downward across many rows.